# Mandatory one to many relationship in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

Suppose I've a model `OwnedCar` (cars are owned, not shared by passengers) and a model `Passenger` (passenger includes the driver of the bus). The models are read/write able via [DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) and admin interface.

How can I enforce that each car has at least one passenger and potentially several passengers (mandatory one-to-many relationship)? How/where do I have to implement validation before a model is created?

Comment: Read [this](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation). This is where you validate data, in your serializer.

Comment: @dirkgroten Thanks!

Comment: Note that if you also want to have validation in django-admin, you should validate in the form (override the form in your `ModelAdmin`). `Form` in plain Django is the equivalent to `Serializer` in DRF. That's assuming the car creation form gets the list of passengers and driver at the same time as the rest of the car information. Otherwise, what you want is not possible, as I mention in the comments below the answer, you can't actually assign passengers before the car object is saved.

Comment: @dirkgroten I forgot to mention that I use a JS frontend. But cause I integrate it via the RESTful API the validation in the serializer should do the job I guess.

Answer (score 0):

From [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) you should use Model.clean()

> This method should be used to provide custom model validation, and to
>   modify attributes on your model if desired. For instance, you could
>   use it to automatically provide a value for a field, or to do
>   validation that requires access to more than a single field

Your code should look something like this

```
class Car(models.Model):
    ...
    def clean(self):
        if self.passangers.count() == 0:
            raise ValidationError(_('Car cannot be empty')) 
        if self.passangers.filter(type='Driver').count() == 0:
            raise ValidationError(_('You need at least one driver in the car.'))
```

Comment: Using the model's clean() method is usually a good option, but for a one-to-many field, this is not going to work, because the `Car` should be created and saved already before you can create the `Passenger` (which has the fk to `Car`). So your clean method will always fail (it's called before the `Car` is saved).

Comment: Pls provide the code for `Passenger` for completness as well.

Comment: @dirkgroten what's wrong with creating `Passanger` first? If you want want to be able to create empty cars there's not point to validate `Car`.

Comment: @FilipMłynarski With mandatory I mean that a `Car` has at least one associated `Passenger`. THis implies that the `Car` model should be created only if at least one `Passenger` is assigned.

Comment: @FilipMłynarski My assumption is that a `Passenger` has a foreign key to `Car`. Even if that fk may be `None`, ie. you can create the passenger first, how is your `clean()` method going to work? When it's called when validating the input data to create a `Car`, the `Car` isn't saved yet, so it doesn't have pk. The passengers cannot be assigned to the car because the car needs to have a pk to be assigned as fk to a `Passenger`. So `self.passengers.count()` is always 0.